# Error with QObject::connect()

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qobject, qt-signals

I am trying to run `QTimer` and have it warn me when `timeout`ing. To do so, I use `slot` and `signal` to link the two.

The `guy.h`:

```
#ifndef GUY_H
#define GUY_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>

class Guy : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    Guy(int x, int y);

    void timerStart();

public slots:
    void onTimeOutTimer();

    [...]

    QTimer *timer;
}

#endif // GUY_H
```

The `guy.cpp`:

```
#include "guy.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

Guy::Guy(int x, int y)
{
    timer = new QTimer();
}

void Guy::timerStart()
{
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeOutTimer()));
    this->timer->setInterval(1000);
    this->timer->start();
    std::cout << "starting timer" << std::endl;
}

void Guy::onTimeOutTimer()
{
    std::cout << "check" << std::endl;
}
```

But as an ouput, I get this error:

```
No matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QTimer*&, const char*, Guy* const, const char*)'
```

As I undertsand it is that `QTimer` is no `QObject` required as first input of the function `connect()`, but the documentation specifies `QTimer` inherits from `QObject`.
I have no clue here.

Comment: signal and slots only work with subclasses of QObject, QGraphicsItem isn't one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inherit from QObject, too, to get this working as signals and slots are availabl for QObjects. `QGraphicsItem` does not inherit `QObject`, not even indirectly.

Not only that, you will also need to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro as follows:

```
class Guy : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}
```

or even better because QGraphicsObject inherits QObject and QGraphicsItem.

```
...
#include <QGraphicsObject>
...

class Guy : public QGraphicsQObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}
```

Also, if you make this change, I suggest to change the `QObject::connect` to `connect` as you do not need to indicate the `QObject::` scope then.

On a side note, including `stdio.h` does not seem to make sense here.

Furthermore, allocating the QTimer instance on the heap looks like wasteful to me. It is not only leaking the memory, but also adds additional complexity. Even if you allocate it on the heap, you should pass this as the parent and use the initializer list or C++11 style initialization. Also, if you allocate it on the heap, you could use forward declaration in the header.

If the slot is not used outside the class, you should also make that private.

It is probably also a bad idea to make the timer member public. Hopefully you do not do that.

Comment: Thanks. But while inheriting the `QObject`, I get those: `staticMeaObject is not a member of QGraphicsItem`, `qt_metacast is not a member of QGraphicsItem`, and `qt_metacall is not a member of QGraphicsItem`. It is going deep.

Comment: You can try `run qmake` and rebuild your project after making these changes

Comment: @wipman: you need to rerun mocs, which happens automatically if you run qmake.

Comment: Note that if you have a lot of graphics items beware that QObject is pretty heavy

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from `QGraphicsObject` which provides a base class for all graphics items that require signals, slots and inherits `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject`. Also add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you use new Qt5 style connects as in

```
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Guy::onTimeOutTimer)
```

The `onTimeOutTimer` function does not need to be marked as slot, and `Guy` could stay a non-QObject. Much slimmer and less macros involved.